# Link and call two separate mains

Tags: c, gcc, linker, ld

Is it possible through some linker magic to link together two files with two separate `main()`s, then add a third controlling `main()` that would decide at run time which of the other two mains to call?

So imagine:

```
/* test1.c */
include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Test1\n");
}

/* test2.c */
include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Test2\n");
}

/* controller.c */
int main()
{
    int x;
    // x gets set somehow
    if (x == 1)
        // call main from test1.c
    else if (x == 2)
        // call main from test2.c
}
```

I realize that this may be a weird question, but I'm trying to work around a constraint on a Cray supercomputer that allows me to run only a single executable per node. And I explicitly don't want to modify `test1.c` and `test2.c`.

Comment: GCC is gonna commit suicide!

Comment: Not necessarily. `ld` has some pretty powerful features. I'm just not sure if they are powerful enough for this, or how exactly to use them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try it with PIEs and dynamic linking:

```
/* controller.c */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int retval, (*pmain)(int argc, char *argv[]);
    void *prg = dlopen(argv[1], RTLD_LAZY);

    pmain = dlsym(prg, "main");
    retval = (*pmain)(argc - 1, &argv[1]);
    dlclose(prg);
    return retval;
}
```

Compile and run, it works on my Linux:

```
gcc controller.c -o controller -ldl
gcc -fPIE -pie -Wl,--export-dynamic test1.c -o test1
gcc -fPIE -pie -Wl,--export-dynamic test2.c -o test2
./controller ./test1
Test1
./controller ./test2
Test2
```

Comment: Very nice and clean solution. This works on my desktop. Let me see what happens on a Cray. If it works, I'll accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

In short, there's no possible way. Not directly anyway.

A possible solution is to use e.g. `system` (or `fork` and `exec` yourself) to run the specific program externally in a new process.

Another solution is to put the functionality from the different `main` functions in separate functions, and have `main` be conditionally compiled in if a specific preprocessor macro is defined, and the `main` functions just call the special functions that do the actual work.

Comment: `exec`/`system` are non-starters for me. A process that tries to issue such a call gets killed. The second solution is obvious, but requires modifying the sources, which I don't want to do. It's not really clear to me that what I want is impossible. `ld` does have a way to wrap symbols. And it's also possible to use a symbol other than `start` as the entry into the code.

Comment: @foxcub Sure you could try to wrap the `main` functions, but how would the linker know which `main` function to wrap? As for telling the linker to use another start function, that only is for the "controller" file, as the others will not really be called as "main" functions, besides, making your own "start" function is most likely nothing you would want to do.

Comment: Well, I'm trying to imagine something like I create a file `test1-wrapped.o`, where `main` (or whatever the appropriate symbol in `test1.o` is) gets renamed to `test1_main`, same deal with `test2`, and then `controller` can distinguish between them. As for making my own "start", I don't see how it would be helpful, but if it were, I'd be more than happy to do it.